# How to Left Join using Djangos ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, left-join

I have to following models:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    audio_files = models.ManyToManyField(AudioFile, related_name='in_playlists',

class AudioFile(models.Model):
    listeners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='listened_to', through='Progress', blank=True)

class Progress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(AudioFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    progress = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Now I want a Django Query which lists all AudioFiles in a playlist but also attaches the progress in them for a specific user. In SQL this would be a `LEFT JOIN`. But I'm sure this is possible with django ORM as well.

I have tried:

`playlistXYZ.audio_files.all().annotate(progress_num=models.Case(models.When(listeners__pk=1, then=models.F('listeners__progress__progress')), default=models.Value(0), output_field=models.FloatField()))`

But it doesn't do what i want.